# jquery next() to skip label

Tags: jquery, label, jquery-selectors

I have a generic function that populates a 2nd field from a first.
In cases where there is a label, it creates a problem, as the label is the

```
next()
```

element.

So, i end up with:

```
function buildoptions(el){
  var element = el.id;
  var $flda = $('#'+element);   
  var $fldb = $flda.next().next();  //double here to skip the label
      .....
}
```

but of course, i have a few fields that don't have labels so this breaks...

I was thinking

```
var $fldb = $flda.next().not(label);
```

would work, but it does not.  It actually throws an error

```
Error: 'label' is undefined
```

ideas?

HTML looks like:

```
<label for="inp_29">Select drives next</label>
<select id="inp_29" name="driver1" onchange="buildoptions(this);">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
</select>

<!--* SOMETIMES OPTIONAL LABEL*-->
 <label for="inp_30">No default options</label>
<!--* END SOMETIMES OPTIONAL LABEL*-->
<select id="inp_30" name="filler1">
  <option value="Select Driver First">Select Driver First</option>
</select>
```

I also have a tabular case:

```
<TR id="dynrow_table35_1" class="">
<TD class="odd">  
<LABEL for="inp_331">absel</LABEL>
<SELECT id="inp_331" onchange="buildoptions(this);" name="absel_1"> 
<OPTION value="">Select</OPTION>
<OPTION value="option1">option1</OPTION>
<OPTION value="option2">option2</OPTION>
</SELECT></TD>
<TD class="odd"><LABEL for="inp_341">No default options</LABEL>
<SELECT id="inp_341" name="abfil1">
<OPTION value="Select Driver First">Select Driver First</OPTION>
</SELECT> </TD>
</TR>
```

id's are dynamicly built and i will never know their actual ID.

Comment: What about `$flda.nextAll('input').eq(0)`

Comment: `.not(label)` misses quotes ! => `.not('label')` ... AGILE matter `^^`

Comment: html added.   using the single quotes returns no error, but does not work (2nd list not populated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this ..

```
var $fldb = $flda.nextAll('input').eq(0);
```

Comment: or maybe `$flda.siblings('input').eq(0);` "eq(0)" is not compulsory if you know there will not have more than another input among siblings..

Comment: This is a dynamic form, so there may be many or no other inputs related.  And does 'input' cover 'select' ?

Comment: no, it doesn't so consider `$flda.siblings('input, select').eq(0);`

Comment: It will always be the 'NEXT' element, but that element may have a label that needs to be skipped.

Comment: All right then, so this selector `'input, select'` should do the trick `;)`

Comment: siblings seems to cause weird behavoir when there's more than one of these.  ie, 2 blocks of the above html, when i choose the 2nd row, the first row driver gets changed, not the 2nd row filler.

var $fldb = $flda.next('input, select').eq(0);  doesn't work at all.

var $fldb = $flda.nextAll('input, select').eq(0); works with a label, but not without.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39076/discussion-between-f00bar-and-briansol)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the chat is blocked at my firewall and i cannot.  :(

Comment: Too bad, well you just got your solution so let's end this discussion ; Good luck the work ahead `;)`

Comment: var $fldb = $flda.nextAll('select').eq(0); seems to work the most reliably, but fails in the tabular method I just added to the markup above.

Comment: If the next input/select is on the same row then try `$flda.closest('tr').find('input,select').not($flda[0]).eq(0);` check the documentation [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/) `;)`

Comment: Getting closer if($flda.parent().attr('class')=="odd"||$flda.parent().attr('class')=="even"){ //in a table $fldb = $flda.closest('tr').find('select').not($flda[0]).eq(0); } else { $fldb = $flda.nextAll('select').eq(0); }   This works in both cases when there is only 1 look up in a row.   a 2nd or more look up ends up changing the 1st 'driver' select.   Is there a way to get the index of $flda and put that as the eq(>index)?

Comment: $fldb = $flda.parent().next().find('select'); seems to do it reliably.  Thanks for guding me int he right direction.